# Backend Testing response returning _body instead of body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am currently doing backend testing using Mocha Chai to test our mongoose backend. We have set up our tests using Gitlab Runner CI/CD and has suddenly started returning all commits as a failed test. We then try to retry old successful tests and still received failure upon retry. We also tried to run the test locally and it is returning as a successful test.

After further digging through the Gitlab Runner error log, we have found an assertion error caused by

```
 expect(testResult).to.include.keys("status", "body");
```

with the error code

```
 AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to contain keys 'status', and 'body'
  + expected - actual

   [
  -  "_body"
  -  "_events"
  -  "_eventsCount"
  -  "_maxListeners"
  -  "accepted"
  -  "badRequest"
  -  "buffered"
  -  "charset"
  -  "clientError"
  -  "created"
  -  "error"
  -  "files"
  -  "forbidden"
  -  "header"
  -  "headers"
  -  "info"
  -  "links"
  -  "noContent"
  -  "notAcceptable"
  -  "notFound"
  -  "ok"
  -  "pipe"
  -  "redirect"
  -  "redirects"
  -  "req"
  -  "request"
  -  "res"
  -  "serverError"
  -  "setEncoding"
  +  "body"
     "status"
  -  "statusCode"
  -  "statusType"
  -  "text"
  -  "type"
  -  "unauthorized"
  -  "unprocessableEntity"
  -  Symbol(kCapture)
   ]
```

I have tried changing our chai script to include.keys("status","_body") which solves the issue. However, it is unrealistic due to the amount of tests this sudden error is affecting. Furthermore, it would cause errors on our local testing. This issue started to appear on early January

Any suggestions on what might be causing the difference between response on Gitlab Runner and local testing?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage so find the cause of this behavior ?